# comparing to string arrays, disregarding caps using HashSet?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to compare two arrays and save matching words into a new array "output" using HashSet. It works, but it is case sensitive. How can I do the same with matching words, regardless the case? Thanks!

```
    final String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
    final String[] input = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.input);

    final HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
    set.retainAll(Arrays.asList(input));
    String[] output = {};
    output = set.toArray(output);
```

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to call [toLowerCase()](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_tolowercase.asp) on the Strings before you break them down into tokens.

Comment: thanks! but does that mean I have to convert my array to simple string? I wouldn't wanna do that... ? new to coding... :D

Comment: You should already have the String in it's whole form before converting it to an array, correct? You would convert it then. Say for your first array, you would just add it before the `.split()` call like `final String[] tokens = text.toLowerCase().split(" ");`. As for your `R.array.input`, you may need to store it in lower case form to ensure matching capability or create a method with reference to another storage of the lower case version.

Answer (score 0):

To find the intersection between the two lists regardless of case you'll need to create sets of lower(or upper) case versions of the strings, as in:

```
String[] a1 = {"aBc", "deF", "Ghk"};
String[] a2 = {"Abc", "ghK", "lmN"};

Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>();
for(String a : a1) s1.add(a.toLowerCase());

Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>();
for(String a : a2) s2.add(a.toLowerCase());

s1.retainAll(s2);

System.out.println(s1);
```

Output:

```
[abc, ghk]
```

However, if you want to report the original versions of the matching strings you'll need to keep a mapping between lowercase and original versions, as in:

```
String[] a1 = {"aBc", "deF", "Ghk"};
String[] a2 = {"Abc", "ghK", "lmN"};

Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<>();
for(String a : a1) m1.put(a.toLowerCase(), a);

Map<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<>();
for(String a : a2) m2.put(a.toLowerCase(), a);

m1.keySet().retainAll(m2.keySet());

System.out.println(m1.values());
for(String s : m1.keySet())
    System.out.println(m1.get(s) + " : " + m2.get(s));
```

Output:

```
[aBc, Ghk]
aBc : Abc
Ghk : ghK
```

Comment: thank you, Sir!!! this is what I was looking for! it worked!! appreciated!!!